# Unable to use cublasXt

Tags: cuda, cublas

I tried the following simple program using cublasXt to multiply two matrices. I get all zero output. Can someone let me know why? My computer can use other cuda libraries normally, and I have two GPUs. My machine is 64bit, as is required by cublasXt.

Btw, I've checked that none of the function calls in the program returns error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cublasXt.h"
#include <curand.h>

void fill(double* &x, long m, long n, double val) {
  x = new double[m * n];
  for (long i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (long j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      x[i * n + j] = val;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  cublasXtHandle_t xt_;
  cublasXtCreate(&xt_);

  double *A, *B, *C;
  long m = 10, n = 10, k = 20;

  fill(A, m, k, 0.2);
  fill(B, k, n, 0.3);
  fill(C, m, n, 0.0);

  double alpha = 1.0;
  double beta = 0.0;

  cublasXtDgemm(xt_, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
    m, n, k, &alpha, A, m, B, k, &beta, C, m
  );

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      printf ("%lf ", C[i *n + j]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }

  cublasXtDestroy(xt_);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe you still need to do memory management for the device. I do not think that CUBLAS automatically allocates, copies, and deallocates memory for the device. Look at the cuda sample samples/7_CUDALibraries/simpleCUBLAS/simpleCUBLAS.cpp

Comment: cublasXt is different than ordinary cublas.  Once you specify the devices to use, it handles allocations.

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen: you are right it does not deallocate the host memory for me. I'm just simplifying it when asking the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, understood. Was quite a Duh moment for me as it has to allocate and deallocate everything because it needs to partition it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that you have no call to [cublasXtDeviceSelect](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublasxt_deviceSelect).  This is a necessary part of a cublasXt code, to tell the CUBLAS runtime how many devices to use and which devices to use.

As a simple proof point, try adding the following immediately after your handle creation call:

```
if(cublasXtCreate(&xt_) != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {printf("handle create fail\n"); return 1;}
int devices[1] = { 0 };  // add this line
if(cublasXtDeviceSelect(xt_, 1, devices) != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {printf("set devices fail\n"); return 1;} // add this line
```

This should cause your output to change from all zero's to all 1.2 (although only using 1 GPU)

However you will probably want to read the section of the documentation I linked above (for example if you want to use 2 GPUs, and they are of the correct type).  cublasXt functionality at this time, that is included in the toolkit, for multi-GPU usage is limited to 2 devices (but note my comments below) and those 2 GPUs must be on a dual-GPU board, such as a Tesla K10 or GeForce GTX 690 (I think Titan Z or Tesla K80 should also work, just to pick other examples).

Additional details of licensing are [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublasxt).  You can get an evaluation version of the "Premier" package that has fewer restrictions on GPUs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought cudaXtDeviceSelect is to narrow down the range of GPUs.